# Randomly my Mouse Scroll wheel controls volume

Tags: mac, mouse, error, macos

I was just doing some productivity on my mac and have my gaming mouse connected to my mac as usual but out of the blue without me changing anything, my mouse wheel is now controlling my volume and if I middle click it plays and pauses. I don't like this and want to change it back. Does anyone know how to fix this

Answer (score 5):

nevermind I tried restarting but that did nothing so I just re-plugged in the mouse and it worked fine. I believe this problem occurred because it's in a usb hub with my keyboard so it might have confused it. I believe that's the case with this problem.

Comment: You know you could just delete the question.

Comment: This Q and A actually helped me, albeit indirectly. I have a wireless mouse on my Mac. Just unplugging/replugging the dongle didn't fix it, but powering the mouse on and off did. It could be just a problem with the mouse firmware.